# Approximation of Markov sequence

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I need to approximate a Markov sequence with continuous state space by a Markov chain with discrete state space. Are there any ideas or references (papers or books) relating to this problem ? Thanks!

Comment: may be easier to give a design for a specific problem than the more generic one -- do you have a specific scenario in mind?

Comment: For example,  $x_t=\theta x_{t-1}+\xi_t, t\geq 1, x_0=0, \xi_t -iid, \xi_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. Then $x_t$ is a Markov sequence with continuous state space.

Comment: If your state space is $\mathbb R$, for instance, you could take your (discrete) state space to be $\{2^{-N}k\,:\,k\in\mathbb Z\}$ where $N\in\mathbb N$ is fixed. If your original Markov chain is $(X_t)$, then define $Y_t$ to be the point in your discrete state space closest to $X_t$.

Comment: @Jason ...And doing so, one would destroy the Markov property.